# this.$ or this.$$ to select all elements with same id or class name - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have 3 paper-toggle-buttons that I would like to have disabled until I click an "edit" button (makes sense to do that).

I have cobbled this together in a long-winded form, however I wanted to know if there was a way in PolymerJS that you could use either the **this.$.ID-NAME** or the **this.$$('CLASS-NAME')** to select all of the paper-toggle-buttons, assuming that I gave them all the same ID and CLASS names (bad practise to duplicate ID's I know).

Any help is appreciated. I know that it's currently working, but I just want to know if there's an easier way.

I am currently working with the following (the toggle will occur when clicking a button with on-click event "editMode"):

**HTML**

```
<div class="detail info horizontal layout">
    <div class="bodyHeaderText flex">Active User</div>
        <paper-toggle-button class="toggle" id="toggle" checked$="{{isActive}}" disabled></paper-toggle-button>
    </div>
    <div class="detail info horizontal layout">
        <div class="bodyHeaderText flex">Operator</div>
        <paper-toggle-button class="toggle" id="toggle" checked$="{{isOperator}}" disabled></paper-toggle-button>
    </div>
    <div class="detail info horizontal layout">
        <div class="bodyHeaderText flex">Manager</div>
        <paper-toggle-button class="toggle" id="toggle" checked$="{{isManager}}" disabled></paper-toggle-button>
    </div>
```

**PolymerJS**

```
editMode : function() {
          toggle1 = this.$.toggle1;
           toggle2 = this.$.toggle2;
           toggle3 = this.$.toggle3;

           if( EditDiv.style['display'] == 'none' )
           {
            toggle1.toggleAttribute('disabled');
            toggle2.toggleAttribute('disabled');
            toggle3.toggleAttribute('disabled');
           }
           else
           {
              toggle1.toggleAttribute('disabled');
              toggle2.toggleAttribute('disabled');
              toggle3.toggleAttribute('disabled');
           }
        }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. It is forbidden to have more than one element with any given id. ID has to be unique. This is why we have ID **and** class.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look to Polymer [DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api), there're a lof of functions to interact with the DOM. I think you're looking for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.toggle')`

Answer (score 0):

[`$$ returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector.`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom)

you can do

```js
Array
  .from(Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.foo'))
  .forEach($0 => /* do something */)
;
```

Then, just a note, your snippet doesn't make much sense because you are performing the same operation in `if` and `else` statements:

```js
if(expression) {
  toggle1.toggleAttribute('disabled')
} else { 
  toggle1.toggleAttribute('disabled')
}

// is equal to:
toggle1.toggleAttribute('disabled')
```

your code could definitely look like:

```js
{
  editMode() {
  
    return [
      this.$.toggle1,
      this.$.toggle2,
      this.$.toggle3
    ]
      .forEach($0 => $0.toggleAttribute('disabled'))
  }
}
```